# Intuition behind homeomorphism from $B((0, 0), 1) \to \mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

In my notes I have that the following function is a homemorphism from $B((0, 0), 1) \to \mathbb{R^2}$

$$h(x, y) \to \frac{f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} (x, y)$$

where $f = tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$

Can someone explain what is happening here intuitively? It seems like some kind of scaling process, and each $(x, y)$ is getting mapped to a point on the vector that passes throw $(0, 0)$ and $(x, y)$? And this maps points in the domain to all of $\mathbb{R^2}$? I don't see why we need the denominator though...it seems like this scaling process should work just as good if we had -

$$h(x, y) \to f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})(x, y)$$

Comment: Any homeomorphism between $[0,1)$ and $[0, \infty)$ will work, not just the $f$ above. All it does it change the norm of the vector $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the homeomorphism changes the *length* of all vectors while keeping their *direction* unchanged.

The auxiliary function $f$ takes the *old* length of a vector and returns the *new* desired length for it.

Therefore, the scaling factor you need to multiply onto a vector $\vec v$ is $\frac{f(|\vec v|)}{|\vec v|}$, namely the ratio between the new and the old length.

This convention makes it relatively easy to understand what it is $f$ does. If we had, as you suggest, $\vec v\mapsto f(|\vec v|)\vec v$, the new length of the vector would be the old length *times* $f$ of the old length, and it would be more difficult to convince oneself that the result is bijective.

---

On the other hand, this definition does need to be supplemented by saying separately that $h(0,0)=(0,0)$ -- otherwise we'd be dividing by zero.